# Referring to the last item of a list in the next sentence

Tags: single-word-requests

> She spotted things she'd never seen before like three-wheeled bikes
>   and elephants. She caught the sight of **one** of them on the sidewalk.

I want to replace **one** with a word that would make it clear that I'm referring to an elephant.

Comment: "She caught sight of an elephant on the sidewalk."

Comment: @TrevorD Is it possible to use another word? In order to avoid repetition?

Comment: Incidentally, "bike" is a contraction of "bicycle"; "bi-cycle" means *two* wheels. You mean a *tricycle".

Comment: You could say "one of the latter" - but it sounds strange and awkward. It's easier, simpler, and clearer to repeat the word..

Comment: @TrevorD I searched on Google. I think that's how people usulaly refer to them: 
"Samlors (three-wheeled bikes) have been used in Thailand for over 60 years."

Comment: @TrevorD I see. Or should I say "one of the animals" instead?

Comment: No! You could be referring to a different animal.

Comment: @TrevorD, JINX!  I posted my answer at the same time as your comment, apparently.  I don't agree that "one of the latter" is necessarily awkward.  I agree that repeating "elephant" is more awkward - but this is getting into an off-topic area of opinion-based answers.  In any event, I think "latter" will serve to answer OP's question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say, "She caught sight of the ***latter***, lumbering along the sidewalk."  ***"Latter"*** makes it clear that she means the last one in the list and I added "lumbering" because that's how I see it in my mind's eye. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but can I use **latter** to refer to to only one elephant (given the context)?

Comment: Given the context, my example could imply more than one - though it's ambiguous. "one of the latter" would be more specific to state that she saw just one elephant on the sidewalk, at that moment in time.  If you wanted to give the impression that as she scanned the overall scene, there were more than one elephant, you could say "She caught sight of the latter, lumbering along, here and there, along the sidewalks."

Comment: @janoChen _she saw **one of** the latter_.